# External HDD cannot be detected on TV after formating on PS4

Tags: external-hard-drive, formatting, tv, ps4

So I have a Seagate external HDD (1TB) which always worked on my TV.

As some of you may know, with the new PS4 update (4.50) you can now use your external HDD as an expansion storage for your PS4.

The thing is, you need to format your HDD to use it on your PS4. I did this, and know my external HDD cannot be detected anymore on my TV.

I tried to format it again on my PC. Tried NTFS, exFat and even FAT32 (FAT32 give me an error) but it looks that the HDD cannot be detected anymore on my TV. The HDD can be detected and works perfect on my PC, but not the TV anymore. I just keep getting an "storage not found" error on my TV.

Did someone had the same problem? Any possible solutions?

PS: My TV model is an LG 32LH5000

Comment: I have never encountered a Smart TV that supported NTFS.  You mention you got an "error", but don't mention what error you got, you have to provide us all details if you want help.  You don't mention what TV you have, so we are unable to look up the instructions, to acomplish what you want to do ourselfs.

Comment: The error I got is: "storage not found". I don't think it have to to with NTFS because the TV can read another external HDD that is NTFS (this one being a Toshiba HDD)

Comment: My NTFS comment was to highlight the fact, your TV does not supports NTFS, so you shouldn't attempt to use that filesystem on the HDD.  I also indicated that, you didn't provide enough specifics, for me to actually know that though.  I just never encountered one.

Comment: FAT32 and NTFS should work on the LG 32LH5000. My bet is the problem is the partition table.

Comment: What about the partition table? How could I check this?

Comment: The LG article [Connecting USB](http://www.lg.com/hk_en/support/product-help/CT20136005-1436499459857-connecting-external-devices) lists the conditions on the disk. It also shows how the TV can format itself the disk using `Inputs` and then selecting `Format`. For external formatting, FAT32 or NTFS are acceptable when formatted *on a Windows computer*. Remark: You might need to use slow format rather than quick formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks trying to solve, I finally managed to do it:

**1. Go to disk management (My PC -> Manage -> Storage -> Disk Management (Local));**

**2. Right click on the external HDD and delete it;**

**3. At the bottom of the window select the new blank disc with the right click and select "Convert to MBR disc";**

**4. Follow the steps and format to NTFS;**

**5. The external HDD should be working now;**

I hope this helps someone! Thank you all for your kind help!

Comment: This is a formal note about your latest edit. You could edit your answer freely but if you weren't the author, such edit attempt would have to be reviewed by a peer (unless you had enough reputation to edit somebody else's posts on your own). Then the edit would probably be rejected because it made the answer worse. The crucial information ("Convert to MBR disc") is now hidden and needs horizontal scrolling to be seen – at least in my browser. This was not the case with previous non-code formatting. That's why I have reverted your change.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you for the explanation and for reverting the change!

Comment: I have no experience with PS4 but it seems it used GPT while your TV requires MBR. Check if PS4 allows you to format the disk with MBR in the first place. If so, maybe you'll be able to use the disk with both devices.

Answer (score 1):

The LG article [Connecting USB](http://www.lg.com/hk_en/support/product-help/CT20136005-1436499459857-connecting-external-devices) lists the conditions on the disk,
although even compliant devices are not assured of being recognized:

- USB extension cable not advised
- Only FAT32 or NTFS file system *provided by Windows OS*
- Rated voltage of 5 V or less and a rated current of 500 mA or less
- USB hub or hard disk drive with a power supply
- USB Flash Drive of 32 GB or less or a USB HDD of 2 TB or less
- Problems may occur with a USB HDD that has the power-saving function
- The USB *must* be ejected after use

Once the USB is recognized, the TV can itself format the disk by
selecting the connected USB from `Inputs` and then the `Format` button.

My advise is to try another USB disk or stick, while verifying these rather
strict conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Use FAT32. Unless you absolutely have to store individual files >4.0GiB on that disk. Then I guess you have no choice but to use NTFS.

If you have issues after formatting it again.. Try it again. The same thing happened to my with my TV. I guess sometimes there is some minor glitch when formatting that my device was particularly sensitive to.

If you still have no luck, make sure you don't have any weird flags set. Like the OS boot flag, for instance.

Still nothing? Plug it into a Linux computer and zero the entire disk with `dd`. The command will look something like this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

That will basically overwrite the entire disk, including all partitions, etc; with a fresh, blank slate. Just make sure you specify the correct disk. On most systems the internal disk will be first (`/dev/sda`) and the one you want to format will be second (`/dev/sdb`), and so on, but that's not always the case.

It will probably take quite some time, depending on the drive's capacity, but low level formatting will be complete. Then you can can format it with a file system however you like, or however you usually do. And hopefully you should have no problems after that.

Here's the [official documentation](http://www.lg.com/uk/lgecs.downloadFile.ldwf?DOC_ID=KROWM000235786&what=MANUAL&fromSystem=LG.COM&fileId=MSA2x8lLZzJQCfd48LpQ&ORIGINAL_NAME_b1_a1=eng%5B5%5D.pdf) by LG. Skip to page 96 of the manual (actually page 98 of the PDF) and have a read, if that helps.